# Apache TomEE - unable to access "TomEE GUI", "Server Status", "Manager App" and "Host Manager" services

Tags: java, tomcat, jakarta-ee, apache-tomee

I am working with some JEE web app using Apache TomEE (apache-tomee-plus-1.5.2 on localhost) and trying to access these services from links on TomEE's home page.

Now, I remember that earlier when I was starting with developing JEE apps, I was deploying some simple exercises to TomEE server, apps were mostly about session beans and entities accessing some database. Then, I have edited `[tomee]/conf/tomcat-users.xml` file, configured specific roles, username and password (concretely username=`tomee` and password=`tomee`), and I was able to go to `localhost:8080/tomee` (Tomcat GUI), sign in with these credentials and I could see which beans are deployed to server, or which web services.

Now, when I go to `[tomee]/conf` folder, there is `tomcat-users.xml` file and there is also `tomcat-users.xml.original` (which is I believe automatically generated file by TomEE at the moment when I had edited `tomcat-users.xml`)

In both these files, there are following lines:

```
  <role rolename="admin-gui"/>
  <role rolename="tomee-admin"/>
  <role rolename="manager-gui"/>
  <user password="tomee" roles="tomee-admin,manager-gui,admin-gui" username="tomee"/>
```

Question: if these lines are present in tomee's configuration file, why am I not able to access TomEE's services ("TomEE GUI", "Server Status", "Manager App" and "Host Manager")?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem was in `conf/server.xml` file content. I have defined `Realm` tag I am using for accessing database from application. And this `Realm` tag definition should be wrapped inside `Context` tag, which again is inside `Host` tag. Actually, `TomEE server` was trying to look for credentials from my `Realm`, and not from `tomcat-users.xml` file.

Moving `Realm` definition under `Host` tag (`Realm` is also inside `Context` tag), problem is solved.